# Editing user-input string values in Python

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how to edit a string value input by user such that the first character of the string (and every occurrence of that same character) are replaced by another character (ie !)

IE if the user enters Pineapples they get !ineapples
but if they enter pineapples they get !inea!!les

Any help is very much appreciated

Here is what I Have so far

```
string1 = input("Enter a string: ")
svalue1 = string1[0]
string2 = string1.replace('string1[0]' , '!')
```

I'm guessing one of my issues is that I'm not using the replace function properly

Comment: What code have you written so far? It's a better idea to include what you have written so far in the description, so that you can get much quicker help.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'string1[0]'`.

Comment: Just remove the quotation around string1[0], otherwise the whole "string1[0]" is considered as a string

Comment: Yup, removing the quotes worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function:

```
def RepFirstWith(s,c):
    return s.replace(s[0],c)
```

For example:

```
print RepFirstWith('pineapples','!') # !iena!!les
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> s = raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
Please enter a string: pineapples
>>> print s.replace(s[0], '!')
!inea!!les
```

All done and tested in Python shell

The problem was is that you wrote `string1[0]` which literally makes a string that is 'string1[0]' instead of computing that value